OutsidePressHandler automatically getTriggered in ios
This is my react native code.
This is working fine on android but not in ios. When I click on one of the child, onOutsidePress is get triggered.
<OutsidePressHandler
        onOutsidePress={() => {
            console.log("Pressed outside the box!");
            closePopup();
        }}
    >
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate(routes.PROFILE);
                closePopup();
            }}
        >
            <View
                style={{
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                    gap: 10,
                    paddingVertical: 5,
                    paddingHorizontal: 10,
                    borderBottomColor: "#eeeeef",
                    borderBottomWidth: 1,
                }}
            >
                <Text style={{ color: "#000", fontSize: 16 }}>{t("profile")}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate(routes.MY_STRATUM);
                closePopup();
            }}
        >
            <View
                style={{
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                    gap: 10,
                    paddingVertical: 5,
                    paddingHorizontal: 10,
                    borderBottomColor: "#eeeeef",
                    borderBottomWidth: 1,
                }}
            >
                <Text style={{ color: "#000", fontSize: 16 }}>
                    {t("my_stratum")}
                </Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

</OutsidePressHandler>

For solution I replaced TouchableOpacity with View and replaced onPress with onTouchStart. Then it's working fine.
But I have another case where the data is dynamic and more data than these two child, so when I try to scroll it doesn't work. It takes the value on touch.

Hi @Devendra Singh you can go through the below solution

Use TouchableWithoutFeedback to handle touch events more precisely.

Wrap the dynamic content in a ScrollView to handle scrolling.
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const YourComponent = ({ data, closePopup, t, routes }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handlePress = (route) => {
    navigation.navigate(route);
    closePopup();
  };

  return (
    <OutsidePressHandler
      onOutsidePress={() => {
        console.log("Pressed outside the box!");
        closePopup();
      }}
    >
      <ScrollView>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback
            key={index}
            onPress={() => handlePress(item.route)}
          >
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: "row",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
                gap: 10,
                paddingVertical: 5,
                paddingHorizontal: 10,
                borderBottomColor: "#eeeeef",
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
              }}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: "#000", fontSize: 16 }}>{t(item.label)}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </OutsidePressHandler>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;




I tried the above solution with TouchableWithoutFeedback again it's triggering the OutsidePressHandler.
Later, in View I added onTouchEnd and stopped propagation it also didn't work, but It worked with onTouchStart.
here is code
`
<View
onTouchStart={(e) => {
e.stopPropagation();
}}

`
